# How to extract a particular value from this data structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column filled with values like this:

```
t=OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Marks'), ('url', 'data/v38.0')])), ('Account', OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Account'), ('url', 'data/v38.0')])), ('ID', 'A200')]))])
```

I've tried to use the following to extract the last value of 'ID':

```
StudentID= t[0]['ID']
```

But it's throwing an error. What is the correct way to access 'ID' value 'A200'?

Comment: What error is your code raising?

Answer (score 2):

Try `StudentID = t['Account']['ID']`.

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> t = OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Marks'), ('url', 'data/v38.0')])), ('Account', OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Account'), ('url', 'data/v38.0')])), ('ID', 'A200')]))])
>>> t['Account']['ID']
'A200'

# a bit more
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(t)
OrderedDict([('attributes',
              OrderedDict([('type', 'Marks'), ('url', 'data/v38.0')])),
             ('Account',
              OrderedDict([('attributes',
                            OrderedDict([('type', 'Account'),
                                         ('url', 'data/v38.0')])),
                           ('ID', 'A200')]))])
```

Comment: hey, thanks! But when I try t['Account']['ID'] , its throwing this error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: With the example you provided, it does not throw an error for me. I attached the output I get to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Should access it like this:

```py
t['Account']['ID']
```

Comment: hey, thanks! But when I try t['Account']['ID'] , its throwing this error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to access this is:
`t['Account']['ID']`

Comment: hey, thanks! But when I try t['Account']['ID'] , its throwing this error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the object to see how it is set up:

```
for key, value in t.items():
    print('\t', key)
    for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
        print('\t\t', subkey, subvalue)
```

This will show:

```
 attributes
     type Marks
     url data/v38.0
 Account
     attributes OrderedDict([('type', 'Account'), ('url', 'data/v38.0')])
     ID A200
```

So, Account is the second item, not the first. However, OrderedDicts STILL don't get items by index, but by key. This is because integers are valid keys, and, for example, t[0] is not necessarily the first item inserted if t looks like:

```
t=OrderedDict([(1, 'thing1'), (0, 'thing2')])
```

So the correct way to access this item is:

```
t['Account']['ID']
```

Comment: hey, thanks! But when I try t['Account']['ID'] , its throwing this error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str